# How can i check if there is any record in table based on the column values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have `user_technical_skill` table. This table has
id, user_id, technical_skill_id and technical_skill_name columns.

When i get all data from this table i get response like:

```
[
{
"id": "4bf91b41-1925-47ac-ae87-ffbf07d8aa70",
"user_id": "f4484810-28fd-4534-9b90-8f487f16ffaf",
"technical_skill_id": "911511f5-23dd-4bc9-8d9b-ff59ba60497d",
"technical_skill_name": "Java Script"
},
{
"id": "111d187f-3038-4c10-85e9-b928ce40ea33",
"user_id": "3c9ada9e-7242-437a-9aff-9746516945c6",
"technical_skill_id": "a29b0ff8-9487-41d6-9064-2a7de2cabf2e",
"technical_skill_name": "C#"
}
]
```

when i post new technical skill for some user - for example for user with id  `f4484810-28fd-4534-9b90-8f487f16ffaf` i want to check if there is existing row in this table for him - so to check if this user already have that technical_skill_id

how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do select query with where clause using user_id and technical_skill_id, If it returns any rows then data exists else not.